# Как выставить width и height тегу img?

Tags: php

А как на php узнать размер img ? к примеру надо вывести изображение в таком виде :

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['img_url']?>" alt="" width="$width" height="$height">
```

но обрезать не надо изображение , надо просто вывести размер в тег img,
как это сделать ? 
Я использовал найденный в сети пример :

```html
<?php 

// получаем массив, содержащий размеры изображения 
$size = getimagesize ("http://smartnews.ru/storage/c/2013/09/06/1378468486_705545_97.jpg"); 

// Значение флага,  
// возвращаемого функцией getimagesize() под индексом 2 
// после определения размера изображения 
$flag = array(1=>'GIF', 
             2=>'JPG', 
             3=>'PNG', 
             4=>'SWF', 
             5=>'PSD', 
             6=>'BMP', 
             7=>'TIFF(байтовый порядок intel)', 
             8=>'TIFF(байтовый порядок motorola)', 
             9=>'JPC', 
             10=>'JP2', 
             11=>'JPX'); 

echo "Ширина: " . $size[0] .'<br>'; 
echo "Высота: " . $size[1] .'<br>'; 
echo "Тип изображения: " . $flag[$size[2]] .'<br>'; 
echo "Ширина и Высота: " . $size[3] .'<br>'; 

?>
```

Вот что получилось :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
за что благодарен единственно тому кто помог

Comment: Всё что вам нужно, похоже, уже есть. Не понял что мешает это использовать.

Comment: просто не выводится размер и всё , именно в тег img не выводится

Comment: По-моему надо тему переименовать в `не умею пользоваться оператором echo` :-)

Comment: Шиманский Алексей , я не php прогер но иногда требуется знание

Comment: как здесь любят минусы ставить , сюда не обращусь больше , буду на SO мозги компасировать - там не скупятся на объяснения и на решения и делают это красиво

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё прекрасно выводится:

```
<?php
  $url = "http://smartnews.ru/storage/c/2013/09/06/1378468486_705545_97.jpg";
  $size = getimagesize($url);
?>
<img src="<?=$url?>" alt="" width="<?=$size[0]?>" height="<?=$size[1]?>">
```

> Я использовал найденный в сети пример

Программирование методом Copy+Paste ни к чему хорошему никогда не приводило. Надо ещё хотя бы язык знать и понимать что делаешь... Попробуйте объяснить, что у вас происходит вот здесь:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['img_url']?>" alt="" width="$width" height="$height">
```

Comment: спасибо , работает - скрин работы выложу